# Underscore as argument to javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I always see this:

```
(_, arg1, arg2) => some expresion
```

What does the underscore entail? I assume a 'we don't really mind'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common idiom used to indicate an unused argument.

The convention differs slightly between communities: Erlang commonly suffixes the variable used in the function signature, Prolog adds a single differentiating character while OCaml omits all but the character itself. All are widely understood pieces of metonymy in computer programming.